# Rearrange blocks in django template

Tags: django

I have a base view template and two children that inherit from it.  Although the two children share content defined in the base, I want to show some of it in different order.  I would expect the following to work, but the blocks appear in the same order as the parent on both templates.

Parent:

```
{% block foo %}
   Foo foo foo foo
{% endblock foo %}
{% block bar %}
   Bar bar
{% endblock bar %}
{% block baz %}
   Baz baz
{% endblock baz %}
```

Child A

```
{% block foo %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock foo %}
{% block bar %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock bar %}
{% block baz %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock baz %}
```

Child B

```
{% block bar %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock bar %}
{% block foo %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock foo %}
{% block baz %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock baz %}
```

Comment: That is correct; that is exactly how the templating system works. Do you have a specific question in regards to this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was clear that since the actual behavior was different than what I intended, I was asking how to get what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

Django templates do not work that way.

Docs say: "Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override". So child templates only provide info, the content of a block to parent. And that's all. They do nothing with arrangement.

You need to make another base template and extend it to get another block order on a page.

Comment: Yeah, that was my understanding too.  I misunderstood a coworker's proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving each block into its own template, then

```
{% include "foo.html" %}
{% include "bar.html" %}
{% include "baz.html" %}
```

in the order I needed.